# Python DateTime to formatted String

Tags: python

I have tried these code:
I want to return a formatted String that is day plus one.

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

d = datetime.date(2014, 11, 2)

dPlusOne = d + timedelta(days=1)

print dPlusOne.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
```

But there is some error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Comment: The code given does not raise any error on Python 2 and an other (SyntaxError) in Python 3.

Comment: the code it all right

Comment: But I really face this problem. WTF you guys negative the question.

Comment: Remove all .pyc files and try again. If you're using an IDE, check it doesn't run stale code. This code definitely does not cause the problem you describe - copy it from this question into a new file and run that to see for yourself. The only way this error could arise is if you would write e.g. `datetime.strftime` instead of `dPlusOne.strftime`.

Comment: I am using IDE, I have tried when I run .py, it causes error, however, if I run selected codes in console, then, no error.

Comment: Then the problem is caused by your IDE. Try to clean your project if the IDE has such a feature, or remove the files from it and import them again. And in the future, please always check your code directly with the python interpreter to verify that the IDE isn't the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

d = date(2014, 11, 2)
dPlusOne = d + timedelta(days=1)

print dPlusOne.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
```

Ouput:

```
03/11/14
```

See:

[image]